# Having USB-C as power delivery and data?

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, usb-c, breakout

so I've looked at many posts on the internet and I cannot find one that answers my question. I want to have a USB-C breakout board (I'm planning to use [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15100)) that will power my [power supply](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465). However, I also want it to act as data transfer to my [Raspberry Pi Zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/). My question is, can I have the 5v and the ground connected to the power supply and then the other data lines going into the MicroUSB port of the Pi? Will it work the same as just plugging something into the the MicroUSB slot of the Pi in the first place?

Comment: Why not buy a Rpi clone with all these features, like RockPi4 or similar. You will find difficult to make a working unit with all these pieces together. It's much more complicated compared to plunging a microUSB.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, that is something that I will look into, but this doesn't answer the question for someone that might have the same one in the future. I will admit I am a noob when it comes to this, but I would appreciate if you could teach me how to make it work, or why it won't work.